# Why cant I branch a TFS project?

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, branch

Its driving me crazy already, I have a folder converted into a branch, when I try to branch this one, the dialog suggests a name, which I accept, then after confirming that I really want to branch I get the nice error message:

```
TF10175: The MYPROJECT-branch team project does not exist.
```

Althoug the branch dialog clearly states: "The new branch will be created and commited as single operation"

Ok, so, when I branch to a existing but empty folder (converted to a branch according the MS doc) I get the opposite message:

```
The item $/MYPROJECT-TEST already exists.
```

So what is it now? It really drives me crazy. I just cant branch this damn project.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to branch a team project root, or branch something into a different team project. Share your source control tree structure from the root down.

Comment: @DanielMann Thats exactly the problem. I did that on the project root. And Source Control Explorer accepts it without any complaints, yet it doesnt work of course. So much for usability. After creating folders/branches all works as expected. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please follow these steps to delete the workspace:

1. In "Team Explorer" select "Pending Changes"
2. Beside the "Check In" button click on "Actions" and select "Manage Workspaces…"
3. Select the Workspace and press "Remove"

Then follow these steps to branch a TFS project

> when I branch to a existing but empty folder

We cannot specify an existing folder as a target. It will create a new folder based on the target path you entered, we should branch to a folder that does not exist. Then we can convert the folder to a branch via the button convert to branch.

Steps:

**a**.

[image]

**b**. Check in the new folder

**c**. Convert the folder test to branch:
[image]

**Update1**

Branch a TFVC project

Steps:

1. Select the TFVC project and convert the project to branch via the button Convert to branch.
2. Branch the TFVC project to an existing project repository folder.

Note: The target folder should not exist until the branch is completed. And we just can branch the project to another project repo folder.

[image]

Comment: See, thats exactly what I was doing, except I did it at the project level, which the Source Control Explorer shouldnt even allow as it doesnt work.

Comment: Hi Hefaistos68,
As test result, I can branch the whole project via the button Convert to branch.

Comment: Hi @Hefaistos68, If you have answer, you can share it here and accept it as answer, in this case, others could directly find the useful solution. Or if you have any concern, please feel free to share it here

Comment: Sorry, but on the project level it doesnt work. I can convert the project to a branch, but i can not branch from there, get the errors i described above. VS 2019 16.7.1

Comment: Hi @Hefaistos68, I have updated the answer, please check it.

Comment: OK, Now I see. The point is that you have to branch into another project in this case. Still, Source Code Explorer could be more explicit here, also the documention.